# Trouble using fullpage.js in Codepen Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js, codepen

I'm new to coding and I've acquired basic CSS and HTML skills, but I'm having trouble integrating fullpage.js into my codepen project (https://codepen.io/Selky/project/editor/DYrVYr )- even uploading the exact demo files used by the author (Alvaro Trigo) I'm still having issues. These are the scripts the demo calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
            menu: '#menu',
            scrollingSpeed: 1000
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'd appreciate any insight into why this isn't working for me. I've looked into other codepen files (such as https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/NxyPPp) and they don't even seem to need anything beyond

`$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
});`

to function properly- but I don't understand why or if I'm able to do the same in the project environment.

Edit: I'm adding the entirety of the current head section of the demo code which I'm unable to make function:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>fullPage.js One Page Scroll Sites</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Alvaro Trigo Lopez" />
    <meta name="description" content="fullPage plugin by Alvaro Trigo. Create fullscreen pages fast and simple. One page scroll like iPhone website." />
    <meta name="keywords"  content="fullpage,jquery,alvaro,trigo,plugin,fullscren,screen,full,iphone5,apple" />
    <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />


    <style>
        /* Sections
         * --------------------------------------- */
        #section0 img,
        #section1 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        }
        #section2 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 52px;
        }
        #section3 img{
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -420px;
        }
        .intro p{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .twitter-share-button{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            right: 149px;
            top: 9px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var console = { log: function() {} };
        </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 1000
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

and my folder structure:  [imgur.com/a/f7KhI3M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfiHG.jpg)

After a few minor changes this is the current head code (still non functional):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>fullPage.js One Page Scroll Sites</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Alvaro Trigo Lopez" />
    <meta name="description" content="fullPage plugin by Alvaro Trigo. Create fullscreen pages fast and simple. One page scroll like iPhone website." />
    <meta name="keywords"  content="fullpage,jquery,alvaro,trigo,plugin,fullscren,screen,full,iphone5,apple" />
    <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullpage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />


    <style>
        /* Sections
         * --------------------------------------- */
        #section0 img,
        #section1 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        }
        #section2 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 52px;
        }
        #section3 img{
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -420px;
        }
        .intro p{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .twitter-share-button{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            right: 149px;
            top: 9px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var console = { log: function() {} };
        </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 1000
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

**Thanks to everyones help I've arrived at the correct header content (I fixed a few file paths and switched to using HTTPS libraries instead of HTTP):**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>fullPage.js One Page Scroll Sites</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Alvaro Trigo Lopez" />
    <meta name="description" content="fullPage plugin by Alvaro Trigo. Create fullscreen pages fast and simple. One page scroll like iPhone website." />
    <meta name="keywords"  content="fullpage,jquery,alvaro,trigo,plugin,fullscren,screen,full,iphone5,apple" />
    <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullpage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />


    <style>
        /* Sections
         * --------------------------------------- */
        #section0 img,
        #section1 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        }
        #section2 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 52px;
        }
        #section3 img{
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -420px;
        }
        .intro p{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .twitter-share-button{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            right: 149px;
            top: 9px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var console = { log: function() {} };
        </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 1000
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with the paths of the files you intend to link. Can you describe the folder structure you have?

Comment: I apologize- I assumed my project folder structure would be visible: https://imgur.com/a/f7KhI3M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using fullPage.js in your HTML, yet, your file name is jquery.fullpage.js. Remember that paths are case sensitive.

> fullpage/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js

is incorrect as well, since you do not have a fullpage folder

```
jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js
```

should be correct instead,

Comment: I've corrected the case of fullPage.js and I'm still having issues. I'm unable to find a "fullpage/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js" in any of my documents- or any further instances of incorrect pathing.

Comment: @selky it was in the DEMO, which I can no longer find in your codepen. The other problem you have is that you have mixed content in the libraries you intend to extract into the page. The reason is that you are using HTTPS as a protocol when you load your codepen, yet your JS and CSS files are loaded using the HTTP protocol. You will need to use the same protocol, so instead of http:// use https://

Comment: Thank you very much! I replaced my index code with that of the demo in order to avoid confusion. I just needed help getting the demo running- I should be able to manage from here.

Using HTTPS libraries(?) instead of HTTP did the trick.

Comment: You are welcome. You are using the same libraries, but extracting them with the HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP protocol. HTTP stands for HyperText Transmit Protocol. The HTTPS protocol is almost the same, but the ending S means Secure.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking the file wrong `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.fullPage.css" />`

It should be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullpage.css" />`

Comment: I've just altered the path in my index.html to correct this (I'd already done this to the paths in the dummy), and neither are working. If I can get the authors demo.html page working I should be able to carry on, on my own.